# Filter out same Data using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, filter, conditional-formatting

This is my data:

```
PART_NUM       REV
C210-272-002    B.
C210-272-003    A.
C210-272-004    A.
C210-272-004    B.
C210-272-005    F.
C222-521-003    B.
C222-521-004    A.
C233-111-010    A.
C233-111-010    B.
C233-221-001    A.
```

so, as u see there are some cells which are the same in part_num but in the rev they might be A or B rev.. so i wanted to filter out the same number with the lastest rev. and it should do it for all the data in the columns. E.G :

```
C210-272-004   B.
C210-272-004   A.
```

i would like to delete/strike/color the row with A as its an old entry...
i tried to find a way and just can't think of one, as i want to do this only with VBA for my studies..

Comment: It's a matter of how you think. You think that you want to "filter out" A, and that isn't sufficiently pragmatic and, probably, not sufficiently generic either. The job is to specify a part number. How? Where? That's the generic part. The system must work for all part numbers.

Comment: Next you want to find the latest REV for that part number. So, you loop through all the part numbers, if there is a match you record the REV in a variable you might call `Rev` and continue searching. If the next REV you find is newer you replace the REV in `Rev` with the new one and continue searching. Repeat the replacement until the end. When the end is reached `Rev` holds the latest version. You might have recorded row numbers parallel to the REV. and deleted an older one whenever you found a newer version.

Comment: The trick is to shorten the loop. You might do so by applying a filter first. or, if you know that the latest version will be at the bottom of the list, start looping from the end. Bear in mind that you would have to start from the end anyway if you intend to delete rows during the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Conditional Formatting Rule using this formula.

```
=CODE($B2)<AGGREGATE(14,6, CODE($B$2:$B$11)/($A$2:$A$11=$A2), 1)
```

[image]

Comment: How do you do your marvellous animated illustrations?

Comment: Wow, thanks this sees easier,  hmm but is there anyways i can do this using VBA? is it possible to use macros recorder for this ? Because i want to learn more about VBA... but still thanks ! This helped

Comment: @variatus its like hes a Magician HAHA :)

Comment: @Variatus - ScreenToGif

Comment: @Jeeped by any chance did u use Vlookup in the formula for excel.. and is there any way this could be done using Vlookup in VBA ? sorry for troubling you :/

Comment: eheh!! :-) , I'm going to go back to all my post and animated it

Comment: @Jeeped - Thanks